# Laravel routing access category and show method

Tags: laravel

To display the blog list i have using the following route

```
// Blog List
Route::name('blog')->get('blog', 'Front\BlogController@index');
```

Ex: http://www.mypropstore.com/blog/

To display the blog category,

```
Route::name('category')->get('blog/{category}', 'Front\PostController@category');
```

Ex: http://www.mypropstore.com/blog/buy-sell

To display the blog details, comments and tag details, we have using "posts" middleware

```
// Posts and comments
Route::prefix('posts')->namespace('Front')->group(function () {
    Route::name('posts.display')->get('{slug}', 'PostController@show');
    Route::name('posts.tag')->get('tag/{tag}', 'PostController@tag');
    Route::name('posts.search')->get('', 'PostController@search');
    Route::name('posts.comments.store')->post('{post}/comments', 'CommentController@store');
    Route::name('posts.comments.comments.store')->post('{post}/comments/{comment}/comments', 'CommentController@store');
    Route::name('posts.comments')->get('{post}/comments/{page}', 'CommentController@comments');
});
```

Ex: http://www.mypropstore.com/posts/apartment-vs-villa-which-is-the-right-choice-for-you

Now i want to change the blog details url page to

http://www.mypropstore.com/blog/apartment-vs-villa-which-is-the-right-choice-for-you-{{blogid}}

Ex: http://www.mypropstore.com/blog/apartment-vs-villa-which-is-the-right-choice-for-you-54

If i change that above format, it conflict category page. Any body knows how to set the routing for blog details page(middleware "posts")

Comment: which are the two routes conflicting???

Comment: category route and blog details route Route::name('category')->get('blog/{category}', 'Front\PostController@category');

Comment: is the category also a number?

Comment: Would I be correct in assuming that `blogId` will be numeric i.e. just numbers?

Comment: Route::get('blog/{content}_{id}', 'Front\PostController@blogdetails')->name('blogdetails' ); URL : http://www.mypropstore.com/blog/apartment-vs-villa-which-is-the-right-choice-for-you_18  I got the following error message Error 404
This page doesn't exist !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `blogid` part, at the end of your suggested route...

```
http://www.mypropstore.com/blog/apartment-vs-villa-which-is-the-right-choice-for-you-{{blogid}}
```

...is *numeric*, you could do something like this:

For your route definition for your post details page, use the following:

```
Route::name('posts.display')
    ->get('blog/{slug}-{id}', 'PostController@show')
    ->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

What this does is ensures that this route is only matched by paths that follow the pattern `blog/{slug}-{id}` but constrains that the `id` part of your route *must* be numeric i.e. consist only of one or more numbers.

You will need to ensure that this route appears *before* the one matching your `category` route or else the `category` route will take precedence.

Your controller should have a show method like this:

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function show($slug, $id)
    {
        // $id will contain the number at the end of the route
        // $slug will contain the slug before the number (without the hyphen)

        // You should be able to do this to get your post.
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);
        dd($post);
    }
}
```

Comment: If i set the routes in web.php            // Blog details
Route::name('posts.display')
    ->get('blog/{slug}-{id}', 'PostController@show')
    ->where('id', '[0-9]+');   I got the following error message on page http://www.mypropstore.com/blog/apartment-vs-villa-which-is-the-right-choice-for-you-18                  Error 404
This page doesn't exist !

Comment: Did you ensure to place that route *before* your `category` route? Also, does `18` definitely refer to a `Post` in your database?

Comment: Thanks. Its working now. http://www.mypropstore.com/blog/apartment-vs-villa-which-is-the-right-choice-for-you_18

Answer (score 0):

Since your categories aren't numbers you could solve the conflict specifying that id will always be a number like this:

```
Route::get('/blog/{id}', 'BlogController@show')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Comment: Route::get('blog/{content}_{id}', 'Front\PostController@blogdetails')->name('blogdetails' ); URL : http://www.mypropstore.com/blog/apartment-vs-villa-which-is-the-right-choice-for-you_18  I got the following error message Error 404
This page doesn't exist !